how to get data based on dropdpwn selection
I am working on laravel project in this i have already develop the full department data functinality like when i penal open user can see all department data now i have add a new thing in this i add a dropdown when user click to dropdown data will filter based on department wise
I am working on laravel project in this i have already develop the full department data functinality like when i penal open user can see all department data now i have add a new thing in this i add a dropdown like
<li>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group d-flex align-items-center">
      <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center me-3" style="background-color: white; padding: 5px; border-radius: 4px;">
        <i class='bx bx-building-house'></i>
        <span class="ms-2">Department</span>
      </a>
      <select id="department" class="form-select w-100">
        <option value="all">All Departments</option> <!-- 'All' Option -->
        @foreach ($department as $item)
            <option value="{{ $item->project_title }}" data-waba="{{ $item->wabanumber }}">
              {{ $item->project_title }}
            </option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<script>
  document.getElementById('department').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var selectedDepartment = this.value;
    window.location.href = "{{ url('/get-total-sent') }}?department=" + selectedDepartment;
  });
</script>

when user click this dropdown i want to filter my widgets according to that , i have 10 widgets in them i show day wise data and also month wise data and data are comming based on campaignid and WABA number     i show you what i have done so far i have already a controller created in this all data showing but i make some changes like department filter and also my query for fetching data
public function getTotalSent(Request $request){
    try {
        $obj = new BroadcastDao();
        $type = $request->input('type');
        $selectedDepartment = $request->input('department');

        $now = CommonFunction::ConvertDate(date('d-m-Y H:i:s', time()), 'B');
        $fromDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 months", strtotime($now)));
        $toDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day", strtotime($now)));

        $condition = ["TO_CHAR(entrytime, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '".date("Y-m-d")."' AND campaign_status !=0"];

        if ($type == 'M') {
            $condition = ["TO_CHAR(entrytime, 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN '".$fromDate."' AND '".$toDate."' AND campaign_status !=0"];
        }  if ($selectedDepartment && $selectedDepartment != 'all') {
            $condition[] = "ezb_wa_campaign_master.campaign_parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM ezb_wa_campaign_parent_master WHERE dept_prj_id IN (SELECT id FROM ezb_department_project_master WHERE project_title = ?))";
            $condition[] = [$selectedDepartment];
        }

        // dd($selectedDepartment);
        if (Session::get('authid') == 4) {
            // $condition[] = "userid='".Session::get('loginid')."'";
        }

        $result = $obj->getRows($condition, 'entrytime');
        $totalSent = [];

        if (is_object($result) && is_countable($result) && count($result) > 0) {
            foreach ($result as $res) {
                $totalSent[] = $res->sent;
                $totalSent[] = $res->delivered;
                $totalSent[] = $res->dbtick;
                $totalSent[] = $res->failed;
            }
        }
        // dd($res);
        return view('dashboard.total-sent', ['data' => $totalSent, 'selectedDepartment' => $selectedDepartment]);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}

This is my view in this i show data based on TYPE same will rander for both month wise and day wise
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div>
        <p class="mb-0 text-secondary">Total Submitted</p>
        <h4 class="my-1">{{array_sum($data)}}</h4>
        <p class="mb-0 font-13 text-success"><i class='bx bxs-up-arrow align-middle'></i><span id="tsspanlable">Today's stats</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="widgets-icons bg-light-success text-secondary ms-auto"><i class='bx bx-check'></i>
</div>
</div>

but with this I didn't get data it redirect me to a different page but i want to filter data on same page when i click all only then it give me right data but it is also on different page apart of that wrong

Reloading a page on dropdown change is challenging. Most sites dont work that way because this means you need to store state before loading in the new page(or completely refresh the page, losing its state).  What most sites do, is make it reactive in JS. This way you dont have to store state in the back-end and can just handle all changes on the fly, on the client side.
